# Cannot install SharePoint 2010 Nov 2016 CU after install Project 2010 CU

Tags: 2010, project-server, cumulative-update, update, patching

In my test machine (SP2010 SP2 with Project 2010), I installed:
November 8, 2016, cumulative update for Project Server 2010 (KB3127952). The installer prompt me to reboot and I do so.

After reboot, I run the installer for "November 8, 2016, cumulative update for SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3127957)" but the detector prompt `There are no products affected by this package installed on this system`.

What should I do?

In this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239177%28v=office.14%29.aspx), it mentioned:

> If you are also installing cumulative updates for SharePoint Server,
> you can install the files now to all servers on the farm. However, do
> not run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on any of the
> servers at this point.

So I think I should install project CU and then sharepoint CU. It is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to install the SharePoint CU separately when you are applying the Project server CU. Reason is Project Server 2010 CU include patches which released in SharePoint Foundation 2010 & SharePoint Server 2010 updates.

Here is the Updates pattern works.

1. If you have SharePoint Foundation 2010 then Apply the SharePoint Foundation 2010 CU.
2. If you have SharePoint Server 2010 Installed then Apply the SharePoint Server CU as it include both Foundation and Server package
3. If you have Project Server 2010 Installed then Apply the Project Server CU as it contains packages from Foundation, SharePoint server and Project Server 2010.

here is extract from msdn Blogs:

> The Project Server 2010 Server Rollup Package contains all the patches
>   released in this Cumulative Update for SharePoint Foundation Server
>   2010, SharePoint Server 2010 and Project Server 2010.

Read More here [Project and Project Server November 2016 Updates Released](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/projectsupport/2016/11/11/project-and-project-server-november-2016-updates-released/) Go to project server 2010 heading.

Comment: Is there any way to verify related SharePoint patches have installed with the Project CU?

Comment: I think you can check it from upgrade and migration page from central admin or add remove program from server...